What does column level encryption achieve?
If I follow MSDN article on column level encryption, it works as suggested:
create certificate testColEncCert with subject='test'
go
create symmetric key testColEncKey with algorithm=AES_256 encryption by certificate testColEncCert
go
create table testColEnc(plain char(1), enc varbinary(160))
go
insert into testColEnc(plain) values ('a')
go
open symmetric key testColEncKey decryption by certificate testColEncCert
go
/* Encrypt with authenticator set to the value of plain itself (not a good idea for production, use a different column such as ID PK) */
update testColEnc set enc=ENCRYPTBYKEY(key_guid('testColEncKey'), plain, 1, HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', convert(varbinary(160), plain)))
go
select * from testColEnc
-- a 0xABC...
go
open symmetric key testColEncKey decryption by certificate testColEncCert
go
select plain, convert(char(1), DECRYPTBYKEY(enc, 1, HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', convert(varbinary(160), plain)))) as enc from testColEnc
-- a a 
go

But now there is an encrypted value in the enc column, which anyone who is in possession of the DB can decrypt. How secure is that? Anyone with access to the media can steal a DB file or its backup and decrypt the value because the cert and key come with it. Where am I wrong?


Anyone with access to the media can steal a DB file or its backup and
decrypt the value because the cert and key come with it. Where am I
wrong?

If you try to restore the backup on another server and open the key you got an error
open symmetric key testColEncKey decryption by certificate testColEncCert

Please create a master key in the database or open the master key in the session before performing this operation.
But to open master key you need a password
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '23987hxJ#KL95234nl0zBe';

So your backup is protected by master key password. I guess it will be the same for attaching.
